# Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

when i change the environment to enable the production mode this message is showen in my console

```
Error: Cannot enable prod mode after platform setup.
at enableProdMode (core.js:7432)
at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at Object.0 (main.ts:18)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
at checkDeferredModules (bootstrap:45)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (bootstrap:32)
at main.js:1
```

in **environment.ts** and **environment.prod.ts**

```
export const environment = {
production: true
};
```

in **main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  
  try {
    enableProdMode();
  } catch(exception) {
    console.error(exception);
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: The only way I can think of that this can happen, short of bugs in dependencies, is to have another call to bootstrapModule or enableProdMode in the root of another module that is loaded right at the start. The most likely candidates are scripts referenced directly from the index page or other scripts listed as main or polyfills in angular.json. There are quite a few issues on github for the same message in older Angular version too, so it could be a toxic combination of versions.